# How do I find an exact text to click using Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a script using Selenium/Chrome webdriver that will find a video uploaded to click based on the title. The title is based on time of the day/date.
Here is what I have so far (after logging in to the page and video title setting automatically),

```
web = webdriver.Chrome()
web.get(...website...)

videoTitle = "June 03, 2021 2nd Service"

time.sleep(5) #allow page to load all elements

lastUpload = web.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[text() = 'videoTitle']").text
print(lastUpload)
lastUpload.click()
```

When the script is finished, I get all text in the page, not just the video title. How do I change that? How do I get just the button for me to click on? The last line fails.

Here is what I see on the page for that specific button,

[image: screenshot of page with html code]

When I run the code, lastUpload prints all the text in the page, which is not clickable.
From what I've seen searching other posts on here it appears that I need to remove "contains" from my search for the text. I did that, however I am getting the same results. Do I need to be more specific?

Last, all the ember### divs that come up generate new numbers every time the page refreshes, so I cannot use that to simply click the last item.

Thanks in advance! Much appreciated.

Comment: can you share the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='June 03, 2021 2nd Service']//ancestor::a[@class='ember-view']").click()
```

Comment: This worked! However, I needed to use a variable in the xpath, which was a quick Google search. My working code is: 

web.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='"+videoTitle+"']//ancestor::a[@class='ember-view']").click()